# What is the event name for start time in calendar of asp.net outlook 2007 add in?

Tags: asp.net, outlook-addin

I am very new in outlook 2007 add in project.
I would like to know the event name when I select the start time in calendar of outlook (as below code that I tried for event). Thanks in advance.

```
namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
    }
    private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
        String expMessage = "Your current folder is " + selectedFolder.Name + ".\n";
        String itemMessage = "Item is unknown.";
        try
        {

            expMessage = expMessage + itemMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            expMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        //  MessageBox.Show(expMessage);
    }
    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what this has to do with ASP.Net... Your C# or VB.Net addin can use the Explorer.SelectionChange event. Explorer object can be retrieved from Application.ActiveEXplorer

When the event fires, read the Explorer.CurrentView property, check if it is an instance of the the CalendarView object and use the CalendarView.SelectedStartTime and SelectedEndTime properties.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned.My problem is when I select at 'Start time', no event fired. 'ThisAddIn_Startup' event fired only when load.

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of your code that does not work the way it should. I have no problem seeing the SelectionChange  fire in OutlookSpy - click Explorer button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab.

Comment: Are you sure this.Application.ActiveExplorer() returns an Explorer object? There might not be an Explorer when Outlook starts up.

Comment: When open outlook, it will got 'ThisAddIn_Startup' function. After load outlook, not going any method.

Comment: Again, when you run your code under the debugger, are you sure currentExplorer is not null?

Comment: Yes, currentExplorer is not null when I run the code under the debugger.

Comment: I don't know. You do see the event firing in in OutlookSpy, right?